# Javascript - tag/mention a person

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage, session-storage

I am trying to make a module in which you can tag/mention a person in your newsfeed. For example, if I am typing @sam then all persons with Sam's name will come up. I am storing the entire user list in JSON in sessionStorage to make them load quickly (loading from Ajax wasn't an option). The module is ready but the problem is currently it's having only 200 users and that's why it's working perfectly. When the website will be having 50-60,000 users, sessionStorage/localStorage won't be the feasible option as it has a capacity of 5 MB only.

The question is, is there any other alternative to these?

FYI - The JSON list contains 4 values: user ID (encrypted), user_name, profile_picture_url, and location.

Comment: `When the website will be having 50-60,000 users` ... so you want the data to be stored in local/session storage (or an alternative since there's a size limit for those) ... how's the data going to get to the client in the first place when your site increases by 300x its current size? FYI, what the JSON looks like is irrelevant, since you've got that part working, it's just a question of where you store/retrieve the data that needs to change

Comment: Yes, definitely. I am having a JSON file and when a user logs in to the site, that will retrieve all users and store them in sessionStorage.

Comment: Just curious, why was loading data asynchronously not an option?

Comment: I always thought that even with the asynchronous, it'll be a huge load to the database (Using AWS's RDS - MySQL). Do you think we're having any other options here?

Comment: `I am having a JSON file and when a user logs in to the site, that will retrieve all users and store them in sessionStorage` is this done using AJAX?

Comment: If you must do it this way, a) how do you know when you need to update the list of users? b) have you looked into `indexed db`? c) have you considered a filtered list after typing say 2 or 3 characters of the username?

Comment: 1. When a user is registered/deleted/updated, we're updating that JSON file.
2. client wants the search to be started from the very first character.
3. Yes, we can try with indexedDB. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: and yes, to store from JSON-file to sessionStorage, it's done using AJAX.

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this? Why not use AJAX to request the data when you need it instead of storing it in the browser where you cannot simply update it?